# HiveConf of name does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hive, aws-glue, amazon-emr

I've created an EMR cluster, and have specified the following in my spark config:

```
hive.metastore.glue.role.arn: arn:aws:iam::omitted:role/EMR_DefaultRole
```

I can confirm that this value has been properly set from the EMR console in AWS:
[image: Hive metastore configuration]

Within my job run logic, I execute

```
spark.sql("show databases").show()
```

This results in the following logs:

```
22/10/22 01:18:18 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.metastore.glue.role.arn does not exist
22/10/22 01:18:18 ERROR AWSGlueClientFactory: Unable to build AWSGlueClient: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
22/10/22 01:18:18 WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Unable to build AWSGlueClient: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
...
```

It *seems* like my Glue client is not able to be instantiated due to that glue role ARN not being found in my conf.

I would really really appreciate some ideas on this, or any debugging suggestions. Anything helps--thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory` class as metastore client factory using the `hive.metastore.client.factory.class` property.

For a full example of a configuration using code please see [Metastore configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-Serverless-UserGuide/metastore-config.html) documentation page and using the `spark-hive-site` classification see the [Use the AWS Glue Data Catalog as the metastore for Spark SQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html) page. Also, please note that in the first case you need to prefix the property name with `spark.hadoop.`.